# Datetime and date-range comparsion

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have datetime-row in mysql database. I have to check time between now and that date using php. If the range is bigger then 1 month - do somtething.

I tried something like this:

```
$dateFromMysql = strtotime($rowData);
$currentDate = date("m/d/y g:i A");
```

And then comparsion by hands. It's ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mydatetime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        OR mydatetime >= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

This query returns all dates that are at least 1 month apart from `NOW()` (either in the past or in the future).

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeFromMysql = strtotime($rowData);
$currentTime = time();

if (abs($timeFromMysql - $currenTime) > 30*24*60*60) {
  // DO!
}
```